# java - modify return value of all getter methods

Tags: java

I have a java class that contains some fields with setters and getters. Something like this:

```
public class Test{
    public String field1;
    public String field2;
    ...

    //Setters and Getters
}
```

I want to do some logic before executing every getter method. In fact I want a method called before calling getter methods, get return value of getter method, modify it and set new value(without changing body of getter methods, if possible using custom annotation). For example:

```
Test test = new Test();
test.setField1("field1");
test.setField2("field2");
```

Now, I want when I use `test.getField1()`, one method called and change the value of `filed1` property. Is there anyway for doing that?

**Edit:** Thanks to **Ambrish** and **Kayaman** I realize that one possible way in my spring mvc application is **AspectJ**. But my question is **Is there anyway for doing it with custom annotation?**

Comment: Did you try using `reflections` or `aspectj`?

Comment: @Ambrish No, I don't familiar with them.

Comment: Try this link: http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/

Comment: Also this: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-java-method-at-runtime/

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AOP library such as AspectJ to define pointcuts for the getter methods. This will allow you to perform things before (and after) calling the method.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Francesco Sure it does. AOP is the perfect tool for this (pretty much the only tool that doesn't require too much effort).

Answer (score 0):

You can explore the following options:

- [AspectJ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) ([Examples](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/))
- [Reflections](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/) ([Examples](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-java-method-at-runtime/))

If your application is `Spring` based them first option, `AspectJ`, is better. `Reflection` can be used anywhere.

Comment: Reflection can't be used to intercept a method call.